# Remove a svg element after transition in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to show a line and make it disappear after a few seconds. I am accomplishing this by drawing a line first and then drawing a white (same as background) after my transition. However, this is creating a problem that this creates a while line on any other SVG elements placed in that position in the meantime.

Is there some way to remove the line I placed after my transition time?

```
$svg_area
.append("line")
.attr("x1",$pair[0][0])
.attr("y1",$pair[0][1])
.attr("x2",$pair[1][0])
.attr("y2", $pair[1][1])
.attr("style","stroke:rgb(255,192,203);stroke-width:1")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attr("style","stroke:rgb(255,255,255)");
```

Comment: have a look at `transition.on("end", callback);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a transition for this

```js
var $svgArea = d3.select('svg')

var myLine = $svgArea.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", 150)
  .attr("x2", 300)
  .attr("y2", 150)
  .attr("style", "stroke:rgb(255,192,203);stroke-width:1")

window.setTimeout(function() {
  myLine.remove()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=300 height=300>
</svg>
```